# Getting Powershell variables into VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I'm trying to get the last logon date for users using the following code. My problem is getting the powershell results from the powershell variable $MailboxData into a VB.net variable.

The `displayname = obj.Members("alias").Value.ToString` line doesn't return anything but an error.

Does anyone have any idea ?

```
Dim scripttext As String

scripttext = "$MailboxData = @() " & vbCrLf & _
            "$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited " & vbCrLf & _
            "foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) { " & _
            "$DBObject = new-object PSObject " & _
            "$DBObject | add-member NoteProperty -Name Alias  $Mailbox.alias " & _
            "$DBObject | add-member NoteProperty -Name LastLogonTime  (Get-MailboxStatistics $mailbox.alias).LastLogonTime " & vbCrLf & _
            "$MailboxData = $MailboxData + $DBObject " & _
            "}" & vbCrLf & _
             "$mailboxData " & vbCrLf


powershell.Commands.AddScript(scripttext)
powershell.Runspace = myRunSpace
results = powershell.Invoke()

Dim displayname As String
Dim lastLogon As String

For Each obj As PSObject In results

    Try
        displayname = obj.Members("alias").Value.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        displayname = Nothing
    End Try

    Try
        lastLogon = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.Members("LastLogonTime").Value.ToString)
    Catch exc As Exception
        lastLogon = Nothing
    End Try
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these lines of your VB code:

```
"foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) { " & _
          "$DBObject = new-object PSObject " & _
          "$DBObject | add-member NoteProperty -Name Alias  $Mailbox.alias " & _
```

Are passed to PowerShell as a single line with no line breaks.  I would either add vbCrLf to the end of each of these lines or use the PowerShell statement separator at the end of each of the `$DBObject` lines e.g.:

```
"foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) { " & _
          "$DBObject = new-object PSObject; " & _
          "$DBObject | add-member NoteProperty -Name Alias  $Mailbox.alias; " & _
```